# Is the sword stance in Like a Dragon: Ishin where swordsmen place their palm flat against the hilt a style of Tennen Rishin-ryū?

Tags: 19th-century, japan, sword, samurai

In the video game [*Like A Dragon: Ishin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_a_Dragon:_Ishin!), a major plot point is finding information about the *Tennen Rishin* style practiced by members of the Shinsengumi during the Bakumatsu period (1853-1867) in Japan.

One distinct characteristic of the *Tennen Rishin* style in-game is that the starting fighting stance has users place their palm flat against the hilt of their sword. While it is true that the real Shinsengumi practiced the *Tennen Rishin-ryū* style, I couldn't find any evidence of them putting their palm flat against their sword. In fact, I cannot find any sword style that adopts this stance.

Is there any evidence users of the *Tennen Rishin-ryū* style put their palm flat against the hilt of the sword? If not, is there any sword style where this was done?

[image: Character with palm against sword]
<sub>[Image from Sirus Gaming](https://sirusgaming.com/like-a-dragon-ishin-chapter-3-mibu-wolves/)</sub>

Comment: Hi and welcome to Hist SE. Could you let us know where you have looked so that those trying to help you don't duplicate your efforts? Thank you.

Comment: Might be a better fit for martial arts SE ... They have sources on martial arts that aren't common for most historians.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question can better be answered on a martial arts forum.

Comment: To my (very) untrained eye, this looks a lot like a Kasumi no Kamae (Kamae="stance"). Searching that stance online, I'm seeing a great variation of what's done with that back hand, from tight grip to loose support. Placing the hand on the back for loose control of direction is something I'm only seeing in shots from that game, but it doesn't seem outside the range of variation of the stance.

Comment: I had a look at a couple of images of this style and it shows the sword being used in one hand - either left or right. The rear hand held like that would allow a hand change but that is speculation not fact.